# Xtext serializer generates not valid DSL

Tags: serialization, dsl, xtext

I have DSL instances and I'm trying to serialize them. I have the following grammar:

```
Database returns schema::Database:
    'database' name=EString  '{'
    (keys+=Key ( "," keys+=Key)*)? )
    ('structures''{' structureList+=(Group|Template)(','structureList+=(Group|Template))* '}')?
    '}'
;

Group returns schema::Group: 
    structureType=StructureType name=EString
    ('{'
        ('table' '{' tableFieldList=FieldList '}')?)
    '}')
```

;

First of all the serializer ignores the comma for the keys and doesn't genereta it between "keys". The second problem is "structures" This keyword is generated for every structure. When I import the files in the DSL Editor, they are not valid, so the grammar is working fine, but not the serializer. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the full version of the grammar that you're having the trouble with makes use of unordered groups, doesn't it? Unordered groups are elements separated by operator "&".

If my assumption is true, then 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=369175
would explain the behavior you're describing.

Comment: yes, i have unordered groups. I saw the explanation and there is a suggestion how to solve the problem, but obsolete. Is there any solution other than changing my grammar?

Comment: it worked! I looked further the Context PDA Provider and managed to set the sequence strategy.